# React Hooks Redux, how to separate dispatch actions into special actions file

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have a simple react hooks app with redux in it, everything is working properly but for the sake of organization i want all my actions to be in the actions.js file. Except i can't use react hooks outside a react component and i need to use some state as well.

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ4N2.png)

As you can see currently addActivity action is in the file that is calling it, what would the activity.js file look like so i could just export the addActivity from it and import it in my original file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create what are called `Action Creators`.

Extract the function `addActivity` to `actions.js` and have it take 2 parameters. At the end of the day, they are just normal functions that return an object.

```
// actions.js
export const addActivityAction = (name, duration) => {
  return {
    type: 'CREATE_ACTIVITY',
    payload: {
      name,
      duration
    }
  }
}
```

And import it and use it wherever you want

```
// AddActivity.js
import { addActivityAction } from 'path/to/actions.js';
const AddActivity = () => {
  ...

  <button onClick={() => dispatch(addActivityAction(data.name, data.duration))}>Add Activity</button>;
}
```

For more: https://read.reduxbook.com/markdown/part1/04-action-creators.html

Comment: Thank you very much, this is gonna help me understand it better as well

Comment: @StevanPopovic You're welcome. An upvote would be appreciated :)

Comment: Also please note that it is generally not the recommended style of redux to declare either actions or action creators by hand any more. The recommended approach is to automatically generate all those using the official redux toolkit. Please see the official redux tutorials for an up-to-date intorduction into modern redux: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: @Siddiq Nx i did upvote, but because i have less than 15 points and this is my first question ever, it can't be seen for some reason :D